# How to formulate an adaptive Levenberg-Marquardt (LM) gradient descent

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, hyperparameter

I am currently programming a sparse bundle adjustment (SBA) for my own problem definition of coordinate calibration.
Applying the [LM algorithm (slide 10)](https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/cv/vorlesungen/WS1415/material/WS_14_05_Bundle.pdf) for parameter optimization, I try to understand how to adapt the damping factor $\lambda$ while performing gradient descent (GD).
The crucial step in GD using LM is $\Theta_{i+1} = \Theta_i - (J'J-\lambda I)^{-1}J'e$, where $\Theta$ are the parameters, $J$ is the Jacobian, $I$ the identity matrix, and $e$ the error.

Compared to a (common) Neuronal Network (NN) issues, I am used to have a learning rate $\alpha$ with the GD formulation of $\Theta_{i+1} = \Theta_i - \alpha \Delta\mathcal{L}$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the loss definition.
$\alpha$ can then be adapted by various [techniques](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/).

How should I adapt $\lambda$ at all? I know that it has a reciprocal effect of the GD behaviour with $\lambda < 1$ if you are far away from the solution, and $\lambda >> 1$ if you are close. Further, $\lambda = 0$ being the Newton GD and $\lambda = 1$ locks the parameter optimization.
That is very empirical and works if I apply parameter adaption during runtime by hand.

Or is it best to keep $\lambda$ fixed and introduce an additional learning rate $\alpha$ to the LM alg.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, as you suspect, better to adjust $\lambda$ at each iteration.  A rough rule of thumb (there are better methods) is to look at whether the objective function was actually improved by more than a user-specified threshold at each step; if it was, divide $\lambda$ by 10 (moving you closer to a Newton-like update), otherwise, multiply $\lambda$ by 10 (moving you closer to a gradient descent update).   In both cases $\lambda$ is subject to upper and lower bounds.

Better, albeit more complex, updating schemes can be found here:

[The Levenberg-Marquardt method for
nonlinear least squares curve-fitting problems](http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/ce281/lm.pdf)